# No puedo mostrar el titulo en esta pagina

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans

Todo funciona correctamente, solo necesito que se muestre el titulo y otros textos, pero no funciona.
El programa solo me muestra el formulario, la caja de texto y el resultado, mas no el titulo que se supone está ahí.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Calcular el precio total</title>
        </head>
        <body>
               <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
        <%
            String cNoches=request.getParameter("CantNoches");
        try {
        jaxws.Calculo_Service service = new jaxws.Calculo_Service();
        jaxws.Calculo port = service.getCalculoPort();
         // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
        double cantNoches = Double.parseDouble(cNoches);
        // TODO process result here
        double result = port.precio(cantNoches);
        out.println("Precio final = "+result+" soles");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO handle custom exceptions here
        }
        %>
        <%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>

            <form>
                Cantidad de noches:
                <input type="text" name="CantNoches">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btCalculo"
                <br><br>       
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hola Isaias, el código sigue igual, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Debe cerrar la etiqueta `form` para que cargue el contenido de este y la cantidad de coches debe estar entre la etiqueta `<p>`

```
  <form>
      <p>Cantidad de noches:</p>
      <input type="text"name="CantNoches">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btCalculo">
      <br><br>      
<form>
```

Comment: Hola, corregí eso y sigue igual.

Comment: También cerrar la etiqueta input, revise el código hay etiquetas sin cerrar

Answer (score 0):

solo te falta cerrar el form

```
<form>
            Cantidad de noches:
            <input type="text" name="CantNoches">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btCalculo"
            <br><br>
</form>
```